# django returns 403 Forbidden on background-image

Tags: css, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I am currently getting a *403 Forbidden error* from the stylesheet loaded by one of my base templates. The path seems correct but the server won't load it.

template **base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load static %}
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- BOOTSTRAP -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- GOOGLE FONTS -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Open+Sans|Oswald|Raleway|Roboto+Condensed|Roboto:300,400,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- NAV BAR CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'static/css/nav_style.css' %}"> <!-- Resource style -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> <!-- Resource jQuery -->
    <script src="{% static 'static/js/modernizr.js' %}"></script> <!-- Modernizr -->    
    <script src="{% static 'static/js/nav_main.js' %}"></script> <!-- Resource Nav -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        {% block body_block %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and my css looks like:
**nav_style.css**

```
.cd-stretchy-nav.edit-content ul a::after {
  right: 7px;
  background-image: url(../img/stretchy_nav_cd-sprite-3.svg);
}
```

which returns the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
```

the **project folder** has the following structure:

```
myproject
-myapp
-- ...
-myproject
-- settings.py
-- ...
```

the specific settings are for another static application serving all my ressources

so for **settings.py** I have a BASE_DIR and a REMOTE_DIR

```
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(REMOTE_DIR,"static/html")
STATIC_ROOT = REMOTE_DIR
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT,"static")

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
STATIC_DIR,
...,
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

and the **static application** as my REMOTE_DIR looks like this:

```
static_app
--admin
---css
---fonts
---img
---js
--static
---css
----nav_style.css
---fonts
---html
----myapp
-----base.html
---img
----stretchy_nav_cd-sprite-3.svg
---js
--...
```

Comment: Could you add a snapshot of your project files and folders?

Comment: @JuanMiGabarron , I added these infos in the original post above.

Comment: Umm weird, maybe you should add "" in the url path of your background-image: `url("../img/stretchy_nav_cd-sprite-3.svg")`

Comment: It does not change anything and looks like a security feature. But I am not sure how to overpass this in django...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not finding a proper and simple answer to this issue yet, the most straightforward solution is to move assets requested from the stylesheet (such as background images) directly into the same folder than the css file and adjust the url accordingly.